# How to use Highchart formatter in rails?

Tags: json, charts, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-5, slim-lang

I want to represent the data through charts in my rails project for which I'm using Highcharts. I was able to integrate that into the project. I don't want to plot the graph if the y-axis value is zero. [Image reference of the current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYZ5k.png)

My code,

```
@chart_data = [[2015, 20], [2016, 31], [2017, 5], [2018, 19], [2019, 0]]
```

```
= column_chart @chart_data, height: '375px', library: {
  xAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Years'}
  },
  yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true, style: {color: '#8b9196'}
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Turn over rate')
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true, style: { color: 'white'}
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'right', x: 0, verticalAlign: 'top', y: -10, floating: true, backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#CCC', borderWidth: 1, shadow: false
  }
}
```

I'm finding the solutions in JavaScript format which are not useful. Based on the search following code should be added as follows

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true, style: { color: 'white'},
        formatter: %|function(){
          if (this.y > 0)
            return this.y;
        }|
      }
    }
  }
```

It is throwing the error [refer to the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42pHU.png). I'm unable to figure out the way to get the desired result. I'm looking for help in rails because the chart is added in the view.

Comment: Hi @Aditya Tiwari, Highcharts requires that `formatter` property be a JS function that can be called.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I tried that but it is throwing error. I have added the image containing the error.

Comment: Sorry, but it is really hard to help you because I do not know ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I was going trough the same problem, using chartkick gem with highcharts library. Since calling the js function on ruby code didn't work, I added it to the application.js file, so when the charts are loaded, this config is applied to the charts. In case you want that config only in a few charts, you have to require it only in the desired views.

```
const Chartkick = require("chartkick");
Chartkick.use(require("highcharts"));

Chartkick.options = {
  library: {
    plotOptions: { 
      column: {
        dataLabels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return (this.y!=0) ? this.y : "";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```